# Will .NET 4.x lambdas work in 3.5 (and lower) after compilation?

Tags: .net, vb.net, lambda, backwards-compatibility

I'm working on an application targeting .NET Framework 4.0. My app uses lambdas mainly to raise events tread-safely, and I want it to be compatible with older .NET Framework versions. I know that the `Sub()` lambda (for example) isn't supported in .NET 3.5... or at least not during compile time.

But what about after the application is compiled? Is the lambda rewritten in the IL so that it will work in .NET 3.5 (and lower) too, or is it limited to .NET 4.x?

**Example of one of my methods:**

```
Private Sub ThreadSafeRaise_ConnectionResponseReceived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As FFTEvents.ConnectionResponseReceivedEventArgs)
    If OwnerForm.InvokeRequired = True Then
        OwnerForm.Invoke(Sub() ThreadSafeRaise_ConnectionResponseReceived(sender, e)) 'Will this work in .NET 3.5 after compilation?
    Else
        RaiseEvent ConnectionResponseReceived(sender, e)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: If you compile it for NET 4.0 it will require NET 4 to run.  The user will have to DL it to use your app, it wont step down to 3.5 if it is not there.

Comment: @Plutonix if that's the case you should make it an answer.

Comment: Updating/DLing the NET assembly is pretty transparent and by this time most system probably have it installed.  The only way to do both would be to have a different solution since as you noted your code would have to be different under 3.5 for any features it doesnt have.

Comment: @Plutonix so just to clarify: .NET 4 applications won't run under 3.5 even if no .NET 4.x specific code is used? Because for some reason, I'd got the idea that .NET 4 applications could run under 3.5.

Comment: An app that targets NET 4. will need NET 4. It cant know what features will get called when loading.

Comment: @Plutonix Okay, thank you. But if you don't mind, make it an answer please, so I can mark this as solved. :)

Comment: Pass.  There are some clever things under the hood somewhat like aliasing for NET 4.5 vs 4.5.1 vs 4.5.2 that I am aware of but not imtimately familiar with to explain.  *Who* does the DL for you when the app starts seems to change too - once it was the job of installers, but I am not sure that Windows Update doesnt do it before you even need it.  This is something Has could give you all the gory details about.

Comment: FYI, lambdas were added [in VS2008](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531253%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), which was for .NET 3.5.  Not that this changes that an assembly compiled for .NET 4 requires .NET 4.  You could target 3.5 and use lambdas - you can even target .NET 2.0 (although you may also need something like [LINQBridge](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqbridge.aspx) to do anything useful.